# clear google spreadsheet data using http

Tags: google-sheets

I have try to clear spreadsheet using http request.

Below is my http request

> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spresheetId/values/B2:B10?key=APIKEY

but json return below error

```
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
"details": [
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
    "links": [
      {
        "description": "Google developer console API key",
        "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/562822880211/apiui/credential"
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
}
```

so how can i clear my spreadsheet using http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy as a webapp you'll get a url that looks something like this: `https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec` add a querystring to it so it looks like this: `https://script.google.com/macros/s/.../exec?ssid=spreadsheetid` only replace spreadsheetid for the real spreadsheet id.

This is the gs file:

```
function clearSpreadSheet() 
{
   var ssid=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('SSID');
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
   var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
   for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
   {
     allSheets[i].clear();//clear all
     //allSheets[i].getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).clear();//everything but first row.   
   }
   return{'clearMessage':'Spreadsheet has been cleared.','ssid':ssid}
}

function doGet(e)
{
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('SSID', e.parameter.ssid)
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('clearss');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)

}
```

This is the clearss.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(dispCleared)
      .clearSpreadSheet();//runs when DOM is loaded
     });
     function dispCleared(data)//runs after spreadsheet is cleared via the SuccessHandler
     {
       $('#clrd').text(data.clearMessage);
       $('#ssid').text('SpreadSheet ID is ' + data.ssid);
     }
     console.log('My Code');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="clrd"></h1>
    <h2 id="ssid"></h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a contained web app.  So load these files into the script editor of a spreadsheet.

Comment: This will clear everything but first row`allSheets[i].getRange(2,1,allSheets[i].getLastRow(),allSheets[i].getLastColumn()).clear();`